# Delete a NEL line break from String using Groovy?

Tags: regex, groovy

I'm trying to delete all the line breaks from lines that I get from a file.
But I can't delete the `NEL` line terminators, I found that the \R Linebreak matcher Any Unicode linebreak sequence, is equivalent to:

- `[\u000D\u000A|[\u000A\u000B\u000C\u000D\u0085\u2028\u2029]`

Below is my code, so using a simple String that contain a `NEL` at the end, the matcher can't found the break line, Any one have any idea whow to do that?

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher
import java.util.regex.Pattern

class LineBreakDeleter {


    static void main (String []args){

                String line="hello";
                Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(/\\R/);
                Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
                if (matcher.find())
                {
                    System.out.println("Found");
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: It looks like your string just has no NEL. [`/\R/` works alright if it is there](https://ideone.com/9RL9m8).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because your regex is wrong.

In a slashy-string the backslash looses its special meaning in terms of the String. So `/\\R/` is equal to `'\\\\R'`, so you are searching for a backslash followed by an upper R. Remove one of the backslashes or make the String with single- or double-quotes and you should find a match.

Comment: thanks , but when I remove 1 backsalch, so i get Caught: java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal/unsupported escape sequence near index 1
\R

Comment: Well, that is because the error is correct and you didn't read the docs properly. ;-) `\R` is mentioned in the section "Perl constructs **not** supported by this class: ", so there is no such pre-defined character class. Just use the long explicit version you also mentioned in your question.

Comment: Thanks again I just used the long explicit one, and that's work well ;)